# Is there a version of fgets that does not terminate at a newline but instead reads a file for a specified number of characters?

Tags: c, linux

I am using the Linux stat function to find the length of a file in bytes and then I am trying the read the entire file (this is so I don't have to check for a null terminator and can create a perfect sized buffer to store the data) (I am not concerned about the file changing during the read). I tried using fgets but quickly remembered that it terminates at a new line and so this will not work. Is there a version of fgets that does not do this?

Comment: Have you tried `read`?

Comment: have you tried `fread`?

Comment: `fread` will try to read as many byrtes as you tell it. But what makes you think the file will have the same number of bytes when you read it as when you used `stat` to get the length? Unless the file is “burned” onto a permanent medium like a DVD, it can change between the `stat` and the read. Instead of expecting there to be no change, you should read and read and read until you reach the end.

Comment: It's a personal script that won't be used seriously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard C library routine `fread` will attempt to read a requested number of bytes (expressed as a number of objects of a given size) from a stream, and the Linux/Unix/POSIX routine `read` will attempt to read a requested number of bytes (expressed as a number of bytes) from a file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

suggest:

use `mmap()` to make the contents available via a simple
memory reference.